# Ansible: iteration over a dict, a list and a list

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I need to know why this piece of code if failing and/or how to achieve it because i am not able to

I ran this piece of ansible, which, using the register list for each host, will check the status of the cert getting the `path` value.
But it seems i am not accessing the dict in the right way.

Data structure got by `register_variable`

```
ok: [node01] => {
  "service_certificate_found": {
      "changed": false,
      "msg": "All items completed",
      "results": [
          {
              "ansible_loop_var": "item",
              "changed": false,
              "examined": 12,
              "failed": false,
              "files": [
                  {
                      "atime": 1552906907.033556,
                      "ctime": 1552906907.033556,
                      "dev": 66305,
                      "gid": 999,
                      "inode": 302256,
                      "isblk": false,
                      "ischr": false,
                      "isdir": false,
                      "isfifo": false,
                      "isgid": false,
                      "islnk": false,
                      "isreg": true,
                      "issock": false,
                      "isuid": false,
                      "mode": "0644",
                      "mtime": 1552906906.6615531,
                      "nlink": 1,
                      "path": "/etc/keys/collectorCA.crt",
                      "rgrp": true,
                      "roth": true,
                      "rusr": true,
                      "size": 2061,
                      "uid": 1012,
                      "wgrp": false,
                      "woth": false,
                      "wusr": true,
                      "xgrp": false,
                      "xoth": false,
                      "xusr": false
                  },
                  {
                      "atime": 1552906902.7015238,
                      "ctime": 1552906902.7015238,
                      "dev": 66305,
                      "gid": 999,
                      "inode": 302254,
                      "isblk": false,
                      "ischr": false,
                      "isdir": false,
                      "isfifo": false,
                      "isgid": false,
                      "islnk": false,
                      "isreg": true,
                      "issock": false,
                      "isuid": false,
                      "mode": "0644",
                      "mtime": 1552906902.3415213,
                      "nlink": 1,
                      "path": "/etc/keys/InterCA.crt",
                      "rgrp": true,
                      "roth": true,
                      "rusr": true,
                      "size": 1554,
                      "uid": 1012,
                      "wgrp": false,
                      "woth": false,
                      "wusr": true,
                      "xgrp": false,
                      "xoth": false,
                      "xusr": false
                  }
              ]
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

*Ansible snippet*

```
- name: Check certificate is valid and on the right place
  block:
  - name: First find the certificates
    find: 
      paths: "{{ item }}"
      recurse: yes
    register: service_certificate_found
    with_items: 
     - "{{ service_certificate_paths }}"


  - name: Now check everyone of them
    openssl_certificate:
      path: "{{ item.item.path }}"
      provider: assertonly
      has_expired: false
    with_items: "{{ service_certificate_found.results }}"
```

*Ansible error*

```
TASK [pb.servicetest : Now check everyone of them] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 26 July 2019  11:58:56 +0200 (0:00:00.055)       0:00:03.856 ***********
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'path'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/Users/me/repos/ansible-servicetest/tasks/main.yml': line 42, column 15, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  - debug: var=service_certificate_found\n              ^ here\n\nThere appears to be both 'k=v' shorthand syntax and YAML in this task. Only one syntax may be used.\n"}
```

Ideas?

Comment: Hi. 1) your registered var example is not complete (syntax error when trying to load it) 2) The error you are pasting has nothing to do with any lines in your snippet: it relates to a debug task having a syntax problem (unsupported mix of k=v + yaml). Please take the time to review ["How to create a minimal reproducible example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the help section.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was only an snippet of of item of a list, now fixed.
But, anyway. I got fixed my self:

This do the trick, specify on the `with_items` loop where to start looping

```
- name: Now check everyone of them
    openssl_certificate:
      path: "{{ item.path }}"
      provider: assertonly
      has_expired: false
    with_items: "{{ service_certificate_found.results[0]['files'] }}"
```